# stop Chrome from asking for proxy credentials

Tags: networking, macos, google-chrome, browser, proxy

I wanted to change my proxy settings for Chrome. I opened the `Network tab` in `Preferences panel` on Mac and entered username and password along with ip and port data. When I opened Chrome browser, it asked for username and password, although I already gave it in the `Network tab`. What would be the workaround for this problem?

Moreover, AuthBrokerAgnet also wants to know username and password. So basically I have to write the same credentials 3 times to change ip. Terrible user experience.

Edit: Network tab

[image]